# text over image does not work when i resize the browser window

Tags: html, css, web

I want the text to be displayed over image. It works well when I see in full screen in my laptop. but when decrease the browser size the text sits  over the image but the text does not get wrapped to be over the image itself.
can anyone help me?

HTML:
                    
                        
              We have high customer rating from all our customers. 
                        
    css:

```
.image {

  position: relative;
}

.text-over {
width:100%;
  z-index: 1;
   position: absolute; 
  color: white;

  font-size:100%;
 bottom:0;
  background-color:#FF0000;

}
.img-responsive{max-width :100%;}
```

Comment: Try replicating with a jsfiddle or something, you'll get a better response if there's something we can play with.

Answer (score 0):

you can set your image as background image. then your text will show over image e.g

```
<style>
div{
background-image:url('pic.jpg');
background-size:cover;
height:100px;
width:100%;
</style>

<div>
<span> Text Over Image</span>
</div>
```